# Object of a class (x) as an attribute of a class (y)

Tags: c#, oop, object, constructor, attributes

I was not able to find an answer to this because I didn't know how to put it.

I have a class Car() and a class Owner(). What I need is to have an object of 'owner', as a simple attribute of my Car() class, so I can pass it as a argument once I instanciate my Car() object.

My Owner() Class:

```
class Owner
{
    public Owner(string address){
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

My Car() Class:

```
class Car
{
    public Car(object owner){ // what type to use?
        this.owner = owner; 
    }

    private object owner; // what type to use?
}
```

And my Main() Class:

```
static void Main(string[] args){
    Owner owner1 = new Owner("street foo city bar");
    Car car1 = new Car(owner1); // this needs to work
}
```

Obviously, using the 'object' type for the attribute didn't do it. Once I print I get 'myProjectName.Owner'. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `public Car(Owner owner)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your code as below, writing public methods to return the objects you want.

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Owner owner1 = new Owner("street foo city bar");
            Car car1 = new Car(owner1); // this needs to work

            Console.WriteLine("Car 1 owner address : " + car1.getOwner().getAddress());
            Console.ReadKey();


        }
    }


    class Car
    {
        private Owner owner;  // same here\
        public Car(Owner owner)
        { // use Owner class
            this.owner = owner;
        }

        public Owner getOwner() // write a public method to return owner
        {
            return this.owner;
        }


    }


    class Owner
    {

        private string address; // this 
        public Owner(string address)
        {

            this.address = address;
        }

        public string getAddress() // write a public method to return address
        {
            return this.address;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Geez, I had already created my getters and setters in order to try that, fortunately I double checked it and my  'public Owner getOwner()' was actually 'public Object getOwner() ' (my former attempt before asking the question). My IDE made me change my setter but not my getter. Thanks for making me realise that.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Car
{
    public Car(Owner owner)
    {
        this.Owner = owner;
    }

    //Since Owner is public, you don't have to create a getter method for this. i.e GetOwner()
    public Owner Owner;
}

public class Owner
{
    //Since address is private, you'll have to create a public getter for this
    private string address;

    public Owner(string address)
    {
        this.address = address;
    }

    //public getter for the address
    public string GetAddress()
    {
        return this.address;
    }
}

public class Main
{
    static void main(string[] args)
    {
        Owner owner1 = new Owner("street address");
        Car car1 = new Car(owner1);

        car1.Owner.GetAddress();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, that seems to be working, but I still get 'myProjectName.Owner', which makes sense. To be honest, I do not want to do anything further with it; I just need to accomplish this: associate a Car to it's owner, on the object creation. Any hints on how to validate that? Like printing the owner variable's name, or accessing one of it's attributes. Something like 'car1.getOwner().getAddress()'.

Comment: @JhonatanCruz you'll have to create the `getAddress()` method in your `Owner` class that returns the `this.address`. I've updated the answer for your question.